# PCIe device discovery algorithm pseudo code

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, pci, pci-e

I have a PCIe model written in System Verilog, although I think this question is language agnostic.  The model performs PCIe configuration reads and writes and memory reads and writes perfectly in simulation.  However, what I need to do is "discover" my PCIe device and configure my config space registers in simulation.  Is there a boiler plate chunk of pseudo code that represents the Linux PCIe enumeration process that I can just add my own models transactions functions too so that I can get a "Bus walk", followed by BAR programming, SR-IOV enable if discovered, MSIx config?   It seems like this would be a common exercise for PCIe device so maybe there is model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't terribly difficult to do. Basically you loop through the config space, checking for each each possible device on the first root bus 0. When a device is found, you allocate a memory space for it based on its requested size and program the BARs accordingly. If you find any bridges, you also configure and enable them - the basic bridge registers for this are standard. This includes assigning the upstream and downstream bus numbers, which then allows you to enumerate the new downstream bus, and so on.

I had to do this once to access a PCI I/O card on a system that had no OS or other software environment. It wasn't too bad and that was across two bridges from two vendors, as well as the I/O card registers and the CPU bus root bridge setup. This was PCI, not PCIe, but it would be very much the same. You could even do it with completely hard-coded numbers if the hardware never changed, but in my case there were a couple variants so I actually had to do some simple enumeration to find the device numbers dynamically. One gotcha is that you may have to delay a bit, or retry, to give all the devices time to come online before you try to access them.

**In doing that I found this book to be invaluable**: [PCI System Architecture (4th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309742). I notice there is also an version for PCIe: [PCI Express System Architecture (1st Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321156307). I would definitely get one of those if you haven't already. These books contain detailed algorithms and explanations about how to do all of this. At the time I didn't really use or refer to any code to speak of, but...

**The best code resource I have found is U-Boot**. It operates at a similarly low-level and is totally self contained and is still fairly small and as simple as possible. For example, the enumeration appears to start with the function `pci_init()` calls a board specific `pci_xxx_init()`. This then sets up the root bridge and then calls `pci_hose_scan_bus()` in [drivers/pci/pci.c](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=tree;f=drivers/pci/pci.c) to do the real work. Also check out the routines in [drivers/pci/pci_auto.c](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=tree;f=drivers/pci/pci_auto.c), as well as the rest of the folder.

For your task you probably only need a very small subset and could just hack out parts of these files into a simple driver. Basically a for() loop and some pci_read/write_config() calls with logic to recognize your device and bridge IDs.